# Angular 2 ngFor can't show one object by index

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, angular2-template

I have problem with loop in my template. I must select one roomRows in tabs for one room (example Kitchen), and I have problem with loop, because I can't select elements by index. This is my template:

```
<tabset #staticTabs>
<div *ngFor="let rooms of renovation">
    <div *ngFor="let room of rooms.rooms;let i = index">
        <tab heading="{{room.roomName}} {{i}}" [attr.data-index]="i">
            <div *ngFor="let row of room.roomRows">
                {{row.typeOfWorks | json}}{{i}}
            </div>
        </tab>
    </div>
</div>
</tabset>
```

And this is part of my json file.

```
                'name': 'remont',
                'zipCode': 500,
                'rooms': [
                    {
                        "roomId": 1,
                        "roomName": "Kitchen",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 2,
                        "roomName": "Toilet",
                        "roomRows": [
                                {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1524500,
                                "costOfWorks": 30,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 5650,
                                "costOfWorks": 14550,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }

                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "roomId": 3,
                        "roomName": "Corridor",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                        {
                        "roomId": 4,
                        "roomName": "Bathroom",
                        "roomRows": [
                            {   
                                "id": 1,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Malowanie ścian",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1500,
                                "costOfWorks": 2100,
                                "accept": false
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 2,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Podłogi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 2650,
                                "costOfWorks": 1800,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 3,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Okna",
                                "costOfMaterials": 1200,
                                "costOfWorks": 450,
                                "accept": true
                                },
                                {
                                "id": 4,
                                "typeOfWorks": "Drzwi",
                                "costOfMaterials": 850,
                                "costOfWorks": 250,
                                "accept": true
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                ]

            },
```

One tab must show all roomRows information to one room. I try add index but my template row is collection of objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it should be in this format

```
<div *ngFor="let rooms of renovation.rooms; let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let row of rooms.roomRows; let j = index">
       {{row.typeOfWorks | json}}{{i}} {{j}}
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/iTtaU4pU07TsQbRwHJ2G?p=preview